# How nameless import and export work in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

We was learning Firebase and the way to connect it with React. Later, I saw the this code snippet:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

I face some confusion on the above code thus wanted ask one question. Firstly, how is it possible that

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
    import 'firebase/auth';
```

get attached to firebase variable automatically, that is, by using firebase we have access to app, firestore and auth since imports of firestore and auth do not have name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

This means "run the code in firebase/firestore, and i don't care if it exports anything"; The code that it's running is [this file here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/index.ts), and part of what that code does is import `firebase` from `@firebase/app` and register itself with it. You import that same `firebase` object, so anything that was added to the object is available to you too.

The lines of code they use to add firestore to firebase are these:

```
export function registerFirestore(instance: FirebaseNamespace): void {
  configureForFirebase(instance);
  instance.registerVersion(name, version);
}

registerFirestore(firebase);
```

Understanding exactly what those are doing will require walking through their codebase to see what's being called ([it ends in this function](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/148db347da5c5c1ee2464068e6c74d734376b9cf/packages/app/src/firebaseNamespaceCore.ts#L175)), but i can demonstrated a simplified equivalent like this:

```
// File 1, the equivalent of firebase/app
export default {}; // no properties on it.
```

```
// File 2, the equivalent of firebase/firestore
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

// mutating the object that was imported
firebase.firestore = "I'm firestore!";
```

```
// Your file
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

console.log(firebase.firestore); // logs out "I'm firestore!", because the second import added a property to the object.
```

Comment: hi thank you for your comments, ok I got that  import 'firebase/firestore'; means run the code in firestore regardless of no export in there. But I cannot get how those two nameless imports got attched to firebase. Pls can you clarify

Comment: Lines 27 through 32 of the file i linked.

Comment: thank you Nicholas:) sorry I just have last question. Why need to import firebase/app instead of just firebase? does app contain something important or ...?

Comment: You can do that if you want everything. They have it split up into packages so you can import just the parts you need and make your code smaller as a result.